# Inconsistent output from AddressSanitizer: intermittent Error SEGV on unknown address

Tags: c, malloc, address-sanitizer

I have the following `C` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void alloc_free() {
  char *s = malloc(sizeof(char));
  *s = 'a';
  printf("%c", *s);
  free(s);
}

int main() {
  alloc_free();
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with Address Sanitizer: `gcc -g3 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -o out/bin/test_free_asan src/test_free.c`

When I run the program, I sometimes get the expected output, which is 'a'. However, other times I encounter an AddressSanitizer error with the message:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==341613==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x61c3ee69ee78 (pc 0x743bdd59e5f7 bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7fff710c2160 T0)
==341613==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
make: *** [Makefile:48: asan-test_free] Error 1
```

I searched for it online, but I don't understand how my code could be related to a NULL pointer dereference, `*s = 'a'` should make the memory allocated by `malloc` contain 'a', why would `free(s)` be freeing a NULL pointer?

I would like to understand why it occurs.
Are there any potential issues in the code that I'm missing or other factors that could contribute to this inconsistency?

Comment: You should check the result of malloc to see if it was successful. If not, `return ;`.

Comment: Thank you @Lundin so it actually was a stupid mistake. I will read more malloc documentation and try to understand why it does error sometime. Thank you